# Does any string can be result of a hash function?

Tags: hash, sha256

I have an interesting question for you.

**Lets pick any string, for example 256 bit string. Now lets assume, that this string should be a result of hash function (SHA-256). Can I always find infinite messages that are sources of this hash?**

I know, that if I pick a message and make its hash, then this hash is hash for infinite number of messages. But is it possible that there would be a string (256 or other bits long) that can not be the result of a hash function?

Lets also assume, that I have absolute brute force power and my abilities in this way are endless.

Comment: SHA-256 can produce all combinations of 256 bits as its output, so any 256 bit string can be the sha-256 hash of something. But what do you mean by "Can I always find its source?" ? Do you want to get the original string before hashing ? That's not feasible as hashing is a one way function.

Comment: Well right I mean "Can I always find infinite messages that are sources of this hash?". Yep Im not looking for original string, Im looking for any string that could result in that hash ;)

Comment: @nos is there a source for your first sentence that all possibilities are generated? It makes sense but I haven't yet found it in various documents.

Comment: @Windkiller Theoretically you can. Practically, this requires a brute force search which might take you a few billion years(or at least much longer than what's feasible - it is at least supposed to be cryptographically secure)

Comment: Could you provide some simple prove that SHA-256 can produce all combinations? Or even better, I would like to know if it is true in some way for all kind of hashes ;)

Comment: @windkiller I believe that takes substantial mathematical proofs, which is not simple. However the SHA-256 spec says it intends the computation of finding a value that computes to a give hash to take 2^n operations, and finding a collision to take 2^n/2, a promise it couldn't give if all 2^n values weren't used.